# First Date is the minDate of the second

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, date

I have these two datepickers :

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="datepickerpopupCtrl">

            <label>Start date:</label>
            <p class="input-group">
                <input ng-model="task.startdate" name="startdate" type="text" class="form-control"
                       uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                       datepicker-options="options"
                       is-open="opened"
                       ng-required="true"
                       close-text="Close"
                       alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
                       show-button-bar="false"
                       placeholder="startdate" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                     </span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-controller="datepickerpopupCtrl">

            <label>End date:</label>
            <p class="input-group">
                <input ng-model="task.enddate" name="enddate" type="text" class="form-control"
                       uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                       datepicker-options="optionsEndDate"
                       is-open="opened"
                       ng-required="true"
                       close-text="Close"
                       alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
                       show-button-bar="false"
                       placeholder="Date de fin"

               />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()"><i
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                     </span>
            </p>
        </div>
```

And I want the `enddate` (second datePicker) to be limited by the first date `startdate`.

Now i've tried this :

```
 function datepickerpopupCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.dt = new Date();
    $scope.open = open;
    $scope.opened = false;
    $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
    $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
    $scope.options = {
        showWeeks: false,
        minDate : new Date(),
        startDate : new Date()
    };
    $scope.optionsEndDate = {
        showWeeks: false,
        minDate : ($scope.task.startdate == undefined) ? new Date() : $scope.task.dateDebut,
        startDate : new Date()
    };
    function open() {
        $scope.opened = true;
    }
}
```

})

but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions will appreciated.thanks

Comment: plunkr/fiddle or codepen pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a `$watch`. The reason it's not working is because you are setting the `minDate` for the second date picker on initialization of your controller. Initially, `$scope.task.startdate` is undefined, so `minDate` is assigned `new Date()` due to your ternary operator. End of story.

Not matter how you change the value of `$scope.task.startdate`, it's too late because you have already set `minDate` to `new Date()` and any changes you make to `$scope.task.startdate` have no effect.

So, the best way to handle this is to initially set `minDate` to `new Date()`, and then setup a watch on `$scope.task.startdate`:

```
$scope.optionsEndDate = {
  showWeeks: false,
  minDate : new Date(),
  startDate : new Date()
};

$scope.$watch('task.startdate', function(newValue) {
  $scope.optionsEndDate.minDate = (newValue == undefined) ? new Date() : newValue;
});
```

Or, optionally, you could just assign `minDate` to be `$scope.task.startdate`, if you don't care when it's undefined:

```
$scope.optionsEndDate = {
  showWeeks: false,
  minDate : $scope.task.startdate,
  startDate : new Date()
};
```

By the way, what the heck is `$scope.dateDebut`?? I only appears once in your code. Is that a typo?